# How to create a custom shape

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a custom shape like this image using CSS HTML :

[image]

I tried using border-radius but it does not stay the same

Comment: Show us your code in a working code snippet

Comment: You know border-radius has 8 variables...right?

Comment: @Paulie_D - this exact shape cannot be done with border-radius. the curve is very specific

Comment: It most certainly **can** be done with border-radius.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `border-top-left-radius` and `border-bottom-left-radius`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {

    padding: 10px;
    background: #1b1bfc;
    border-top-left-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>test</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
shape {

    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;

}
```

If you’re planning on putting the CSS on that page, and not on a separate .css stylesheet then you should put the above inside of style tags like so:

```
<style>
shape {

    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;

}
</style>
```

If you *are* using an external stylesheet then you can simply link it at the top of your document.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SVG for that:

```html
<svg width="173" height="118">
 <g>
  <path id="svg_3" d="m173.00287,117.8624l-86.50198,0l0,0c-47.774,0 -86.49779,1.25536 -86.50191,-58.92873c-0.00412,-60.18451 38.72791,-58.92869 86.50191,-58.92869l86.50198,0l0,117.85742z" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000" fill="#007fff"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

You can edit it however you want...
I used http://editor.method.ac to create it, but you should probbly use Adobe Illustrator because that would be ideal and then save it as `svg` format and drop it into your code either as HTML or as CSS

Answer (score 0):

`border-radius` for each corner takes **two** values

[**Border-radius @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

> The border-radius CSS property allows Web authors to define how rounded border corners are. The curve of each corner is defined using **one or two radii, defining its shape: circle or ellipse.**

So you can apply **multiple** values to each corner

```css
div {
  width: 8em;
  height: 4em;
  background: blue;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top-left-radius: 6em 1.2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6em 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this effect by using the `border-radius` property. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp).

> **Note:** The shape will not be the same as the one posted above.

```css
.shape {
  background: #0677bd;
  border-radius: 6em 0 0 6em / .8em 0 0 .8em;
  height: 40px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```